# object could not be converted to string in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am sending attachments in email.. following is my code in controller

```
    $ad_mail = default.jpg;
    $this->load->helper('path');
    $path = set_realpath('images/');
    $dwnld_file = $this->email->attach($path.$ad_mail);
```

it gives error:-

> object of class CI-EMAIL could not be converted to string

please help

Comment: `$ad_mail = 'default.jpg';`quotes missed

Comment: still not working

Comment: try with `$path = set_realpath('/images/');`